# Converting Kotlin's KClass to regular Class in Java

Tags: kotlin

I am trying call a regular Java method in a Java code as follows:

```
public <T> T proxy(KClass<T> kClass) { 
    // unfortunately nothing like getJavaClass() exists
    return (T) proxy(kClass.getJavaClass()); 
}

public <T> T proxy(Class<T> jClass) {
    return (T) context.getBean(jClass);
}
```

In Kotlin, you can call `.java` on each KClass. This is not the case here and I am unable to extract the Java Class object from KClass. Is there a way to do it?

EDIT: This is trivial in Kotlin, but I am looking for solution in Java code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The functionality *does* exist, just not where it seems to, as `java` is an extension property.

Use the method `JvmClassMappingKt.getJavaClass`.

In Kotlin, extension methods (and property getters/setters) are implemented as `static` methods of their containing class. If you look at the source for `.java` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>), you can see that it is implemented in `JvmClassMapping.kt`.

As the function is package-level and does not have a containing object, it is simply placed into the file `[Filename]Kt` which in this case is `JvmClassMappingKt`.

Here is the source of this extension property:

```
@Suppress("UPPER_BOUND_VIOLATED")
public val <T> KClass<T>.java: Class<T>
    @JvmName("getJavaClass")
    get() = (this as ClassBasedDeclarationContainer).jClass as Class<T>
```

As you can see, the method's name is renamed on the JVM to `getJavaClass`.

In your case, you can try:

```
public <T> T proxy(KClass<T> kClass) { 
    return (T) proxy(JvmClassMappingKt.getJavaClass(kClass)); 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try to use `javaObjectType` on your KClass

The explanation:

> Returns a Java [Class] instance corresponding to the given [KClass] instance.
>   In case of primitive types it returns corresponding wrapper classes.

E.g.

`Boolean::class.javaObjectType`

Comment: I guess I didn't stress the fact I wanted to get the `.javaClass` in a Java file. You can see that at my example. For such the only solution still seems to be `JvmClassMappingKt.getJavaClass(kClass)`.